# Creating CRUD Functions Using Async-Await with Vapor-Fluent - Swift 5.6

Tags: swift, async-await, vapor, vapor-fluent, swift5.6

I'm trying to understand how to create CRUD functions with Vapor. It appears `first()` is optional, but cannot be unwrapped as an optional type

```
func first() -> EventLoopFuture<Token?>
```

Here's my `Token.swift`

```
import Foundation
import Fluent
import Vapor

final class Token: Model {
  // 1
  static let schema = "tokens"

  // 2
  @ID(key: .id)
  var id: UUID?

  // 3
  @Field(key: "token")
  var token: String

  @Field(key: "debug")
  var debug: Bool

  // 4
  init() { }

  init(token: String, debug: Bool) {
    self.token = token
    self.debug = debug
  }
}
```

Here's my `TokenController.swift`

```
import Foundation
import Fluent
import Vapor

struct TokenController {
    func create(req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
        let token = try req.content.decode(Token.self)
        try await token.create(on: req.db)
        return .created
    }
    
    func delete(req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
        guard let token = req.parameters.get("token") else {
            return .badRequest
        }
        
        try await Token.query(on: req.db)
            .filter(\.$token == token)
            .first()
        
        try await delete(req: req.db)

        return .noContent
    }

}

@available(macOS 12, *)
extension TokenController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let tokens = routes.grouped("token")
        tokens.post(use: create)
        tokens.delete(":token", use: delete)
    }
}
```

The return token might not be there, so it should be optional, but I get the familiar error

**Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'EventLoopFuture<Token?>'**

I'm using async-await obviously and not `EventLoopFuture<>` except maybe under the hood, if I understand the [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/async/) correctly.

Based on a tutorial I'm following, this was suggested as a solution to delete rows by getting the first row in the table

```
func delete(req: Request) async throws -> HTTPStatus {
  guard let token = req.parameters.get("token") else {
    return .badRequest
  }

  guard let row = try await Token.query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$token == token)
    .first()
  else {
    return .notFound
  }

  try await row.delete(on: req.db)
  return .noContent
}
```

But this gives me the same error for token, including another error for the `row.delete(on:_)` method

**Value of type 'EventLoopFuture<Token?>' has no member 'delete'**

What am I missing?

• Pouring over the documentation
• Retracing my steps from the tutorial
• Holding my breath until the computer worked

Comment: Do you have the macOS version set to `.v12` and the Swift Tools Version to at least 5.5 in your Package.swift?

Comment: This is the correct answer. I had to do this with every other dependency over the weekend, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to give the compiler a hand and force it to use the async version of `.first()`:

```swift
guard let row: Token = try await Token.query(on: req.db)
    .filter(\.$token == token)
    .first()
```

Because the functions have the same signature it can occasionally pick the future version, especially if there are errors elsewhere

Comment: Hey @0xTim. Please update your answer and remove the question mark from Token, i.e. `Token?` and I'll accept it.

Comment: I had to add `@available(macOS 12, *)` to the top of my struct, and then add the type `Token`, not the optional `Token?`